# Add Custom bootstap template to Django CMS Project

Tags: python, django, carousel, django-cms, bootstrap-carousel

I hope you are well. 
The reason i'm writing to you is because ive been utilizing the Django cms bootstrap carousel plug in.

Im all set however i am struggling to figure out how to add me newly added custom template to my application.

Im wondering if there is something i need to add to my settings.py file like CAROUSEL_TEMPLATES = [ ' ' ]

I am not using setup.py

All of the applications are installed via requirements.txt

static and troage files are in AWS and templates are served from the source code of the applictation.

I would be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction?

Djangocms version: Django-cms 3.10

Django version : Django==3.2

Plug in im using:  djangocms-bootstrap 1.1.2

Comment: It would be helpful to know which plug in you are using, as there are a few by that description

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ive edited the question the plug in im using is djangocms-bootstrap 1.1.2 via requirments.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all worked perfectly thank you.The only thing i had to remove the _ from your settings .py suggestion. so it workeed with the following:

```
DJANGOCMS_BOOTSTRAP4_CAROUSEL_TEMPLATES = (
    ('default', ('Default')),
    ('theme', ('Theme')),
)
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You might as well take out the extra braces as well then. That `_()` is for translations.

Comment: Thanks! I owe you one!

Answer (score 1):

The default setting for these templates is;

```
DJANGOCMS_BOOTSTRAP4_CAROUSEL_TEMPLATES = (
    ('default', _('Default')),
)
```

And you can see those default templates [here](https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-bootstrap4/tree/master/djangocms_bootstrap4/contrib/bootstrap4_carousel/templates/djangocms_bootstrap4/carousel/default).

So that default path within the templates directory looks like `templates/djangocms_bootstrap4/carousel/default`

Assuming you have a set of templates you called `theme` you'd change that setting to;

```
DJANGOCMS_BOOTSTRAP4_CAROUSEL_TEMPLATES = (
    ('default', _('Default')),
    ('theme', _('Theme')),
)
```

And you would add your templates in the following directory;

`templates/djangocms_bootstrap4/carousel/theme`